# Change gridview row color after one click

Tags: c#, gridview

I want to change the row color after one click.

```
  private void GridViewRow_MouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        var row = sender as GridViewRow;
        row.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Green);
    }
```

It works if I select the row. The question is if I click again, which means I unselect it, I want to recover the row color as the default one.

How to do it? I couldn't remove the color I added.

Answer (score 0):

Here is option:

```
var green = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Green);
var transparent = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Transparent);
private void GridViewRow_MouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e) {
    var row = sender as GridViewRow;
    if (row.Background == green) {
        row.Background = transparent;
    } else {
        row.Background = green;
    }
}
```

Comment: I use silverlight, can't get `System.Drawing`